# Turning ggplot into function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to convert some ggplot code which is repetitive into function .So that i can call the function whenever it needs or is it possible to write the whole ggplot code inside the function

i put the code inside the function which is repetitve

```
ggplot_common_function = function(text){
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge(width=20),width=10)+theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
    labs(x="", y=text, fill="")+
    theme(axis.title.y =element_text(size=8))+
    scale_x_date(date_breaks ="1 month", date_labels ="%b-%Y")+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE),expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.3)),breaks = integer_breaks())+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#dfe022", "#288D55"))
}
```

And calling the function inside the ggplot but i am getting an error (Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?)

```
ggplotly(ggplot(aggregate(revenue~date+type,data=revenue_data(),FUN=sum),aes(x=date,y=revenue,fill=type,text=paste(revenue)))+
                                           ggplot_common_function("INR (In Lakhs)"),expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.3)),tooltip = c("text"))%>%layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.25, y = -0.2,font=list( family='Arial', size=10, color='black')),xaxis = x_labels,yaxis = y_labels)%>%config(displaylogo = FALSE,modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d', 'toggleSpikelines','hoverClosestCartesian', 'hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d','zoomOut2d'))
```

This is the actual whole ggplot code

```
ggplotly(ggplot(aggregate(revenue~date+type,data=revenue_data(),FUN=sum),aes(x=date,y=revenue,fill=type,text=paste(revenue)))+
                                           geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge(width=0.5),width=0.3)+theme_classic()+
                                           theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom",
                                                 axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
                                           labs(x="", y="INR (In Lakhs)", fill="")+
                                           theme(axis.title.y =element_text(size=8))+
                                           scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE),expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.3)),breaks = integer_breaks())+
                                           scale_fill_manual(values=c("#dfe022", "#288D55")),expand = expansion(mult = c(0,.3)),tooltip = c("text"))%>%layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.25, y = -0.2,font=list( family='Arial', size=10, color='black')),xaxis = x_labels,yaxis = y_labels)%>%config(displaylogo = FALSE,modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d', 'toggleSpikelines','hoverClosestCartesian', 'hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d','zoomOut2d'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `+` to add something to the object created by `ggplot`. If you don't want to have the `ggplot` call within your function, you cannot use `+`. Instead you should let the function return a `list` like in this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
foo <- function(text) list(geom_point(), 
                           labs(x = "", y = text))
ggplot(iris, aes( x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + foo("bar")
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland but is it possible to call the whole plot code inside the function

Comment: Have you understood this answer? What exactly is unclear? What is "the whole plot code"?

Comment: yes in the function i used +symbol next to the geom bar ,theme etc.... in question i update the whole plot code is it possible to convert that into function

Comment: I do not understand. Do you have issues transferring the approach from this answer to your actual code?

Comment: That is fine  Roland in your code instead of foo what if the whole code should be in the 
function ex<- function(x,y){ggplot(iris, aes( x , y )) +geom_point(), labs(x = "", y = text) } ex(Species,Sepal.Length)

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.5/topics/aes_) and numerous answers at Stack Overflow.